# How can I Input in GoLand Terminal

Tags: goland

I can't input in GoLand terminal.

[image: screenshot of GoLand]

[click on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy5Hg.png)

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLRlK.png)

Comment: Have you already restarted your IDE? What happens when you start a new terminal session (click on the `+`)?

Comment: Also, what version of GoLand are you using (Help | About)?

Comment: I tried, version is 2021.1.3

Comment: Do you see any errors/warnings in the logs (Help | Shot Log in Exploer)?

Comment: yea, and updated my question, please click on logs